# Hide / Show without refreshing, change onclick to act like toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Really quick question... and a basic one (it's been way too long a day!).

At the moment clicking Update / View Client loads a php file on to the page without refreshing.  Which is great but what's the easiest way so that clicking the same anchor tag acts more like a toggle (show/hide)?

The jQuery:

```
 $("#searchClient").bind("click", function() {

              $("#search").load("inc/search.php?r=clients")

         });
```

The HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="searchClient"><h3>Update / View Existing Client</h3></a>
<div id="search"></div>
```

I don't want any fancy sliding just plain pop in pop out.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `#search` is hidden to begin with:

```
$("#searchClient").bind("click", function() {
    var $search = $("#search");

    if ($search.is(':hidden')) {
        $search.load("inc/search.php?r=clients", function () {
            $search.show();
        });
    } else {
        $search.hide();
    }
});
```

Otherwise you can track if it's been loaded:

```
$("#searchClient").bind("click", function() {
    var $search = $("#search");

    if ($search.is(':hidden')
        || $search.data('loaded') == undefined) {
        $search.load("inc/search.php?r=clients", function () {
            $search
                .data('loaded', true)
                .show();
        });
    } else {
        $search.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did try both answers but neither seemed to work the first displayed the search.php file however wouldn't hid it on another click the second option didn't display the search.php file.

Comment: The first works as intended as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/3fj8aqo2/ The second is demonstrated as working here: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/3fj8aqo2/1/ (The `{}` is what `/echo/json/` returns on jsfiddle.) There's either something you're omitting or some other issue (are you looking at the console for errors?).

Comment: Sorted :) sorry for the delay and thank you very much